# To find the list of interfaces about a particular node from wireshark logs

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, network-interface

Could you please tell me if there is any way to get the interface details of a particular IP address machine through Wireshark packets. Could you please let me know if there is any approach to get this details programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the actual interface on which the packets are captured along with hardware, OS used.

Open the .pcapng file with the help of Wireshark. I am using Wireshark Version 3.4.2 (v3.4.2-0-ga889cf1b1bf9).

- Click on statistics
- Then select capture File properties

[image]

You can find the interfaces option where exact interface is mentioned for example Wi-Fi interface. In my case Ethernet9 is used.

[image]

If you have connectivity diagram, you can find the opposite end interface easily.

If you don’t have connectivity diagram, you can check the destination MAC address and get the destination vendor details with the help of vendor lookup.

Refer link, https://macvendors.com/
Enter the destination MAC address and get the destination device vendor details easily. You can check the hardware specification of vendor and find the list of interfaces manually.

Answer (score 0):

For doing it Programatically, You can use psutil package of python. This package can provide you the total number of interfaces that are associated with a particular machine.

```
import psutil


def getInterfaces():
    addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs()
    return addrs.keys()
```

It will return the list of the interfaces in dict format.